# what should I do in "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007, oledbexception

Why am I getting this error? 
"OledbException was unhandled"
"Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

There is no problem when I am querying a string data type, but when I am querying a integer data type, I am always getting this problem..

I am using microsoft access 2007

here is my source code:

```
Public Function searchMemberId(ByVal userId As String) As DataSet
    sqlStr = "Select Member_ID From tblMemberInfo Where Member_ID = '" & _
        Val(userId) & "'"
    ds.Clear()
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con.ConnectionString)
    da.Fill(ds, "john")

    Return ds
End Function
```

the data type of Member_ID is autonumber, the error was always pointing to da.Fill(ds, "john")

"ds" is a Dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you query a numeric type, don't use quotes

```sql
SELECT Member_ID 
FROM tblMemberInfo
WHERE Member_ID = 17
```

If you query a string type, do use quotes

```sql
SELECT Member_ID 
FROM tblMemberInfo
WHERE Member_ID = 'john'
```

---

UPDATE

The `Val` function will not help in this case. Simply write

```
sqlStr = "SELECT ... WHERE Member_ID = " & userId
```

If the ID was a string it could contain single quotes that you must escape with double quotes in a SQL string

```
ID = "John's record"
sqlStr = "SELECT ... WHERE Member_ID = '" & ID.Replace("'", "''") & "'"
' ==> "SELECT ... WHERE Member_ID = 'John''s record'"
```

This also helps preventing [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) (Wikipedia). A more professional approach, however, is to use parameters. See Steve's answer and [DataAdapter Parameters (ADO.NET)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbw6zyha%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) on MSDN (especially the "OleDb Parameter Placeholders" and "OleDb Example" sections.

Answer (score 1):

You should use parameters and this type of problems do not occur.

```
sqlStr = "Select Member_ID From tblMemberInfo Where Member_ID = ?" 
ds.Clear() 
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlStr, con.ConnectionString) 
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(userID))
da.Fill(ds, "john") 
Return ds
```